# How to get the particular value from parsed json array by using golang?

Tags: json, parsing, go

I am trying to get direct message from twitter using twitter api. I got the api json array respose like

```js
[{
 "id": 694476444991229955,
 "id_str": "694476444991229955",
 "text": "Got it",
 "sender": {
  "id": 1690262984,
  "id_str": "1690262984",
  "name": "Ashok Kumar T",
  "screen_name": "Ashok_kumar_T",
  "location": "Trivandrum",
  "description": "",
  "url": null
  },
  "protected": false,
  "followers_count": 68,
  "friends_count": 32,
  "listed_count": 0,
  "created_at": "Thu Aug 22 06:52:53 +0000 2013",
  "favourites_count": 5,
  "utc_offset": 19800,
  "time_zone": "Chennai",
  "geo_enabled": true,
  "verified": false,
  "statuses_count": 124,
  "lang": "en",
  "contributors_enabled": false,
  "is_translator": false,
  "is_translation_enabled": false,
  "profile_background_color": "131516",
  "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif",
  "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif",
  "profile_background_tile": true,
  "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg",
  "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg",
  "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1690262984\/1429709252",
  "profile_link_color": "009999",
  "profile_sidebar_border_color": "EEEEEE",
  "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "EFEFEF",
  "profile_text_color": "333333",
  "profile_use_background_image": true,
  "has_extended_profile": false,
  "default_profile": false,
  "default_profile_image": false,
  "following": true,
  "follow_request_sent": false,
  "notifications": false
 }]
```

I have successfully parsed the json.But I cant get the particular data from parsed json. Here my play golang link http://play.golang.org/p/zS42Qws2Di

```js
package main

import (
 "encoding/json"
 "fmt"
 
 
)

type PublicKey struct {
 ID int64
 ID_STR string
 Text string
 SENDER struct {
         ID int64
         ID_STR string
  NAME string
    }
 PROTECTED bool
 FOLLOWERS_COUNT int
 FRIENDS_COUNT int
 LISTED_COUNT int
 
}

type KeysResponse struct {
 Collection []PublicKey
}

func main() {
 s := `[{
 "id": 694476444991229955,
 "id_str": "694476444991229955",
 "text": "Got it",
 "sender": {
  "id": 1690262984,
  "id_str": "1690262984",
  "name": "Ashok Kumar T",
  "screen_name": "Ashok_kumar_T",
  "location": "Trivandrum",
  "description": "",
  "url": null
  },
  "protected": false,
  "followers_count": 68,
  "friends_count": 32,
  "listed_count": 0,
  "created_at": "Thu Aug 22 06:52:53 +0000 2013",
  "favourites_count": 5,
  "utc_offset": 19800,
  "time_zone": "Chennai",
  "geo_enabled": true,
  "verified": false,
  "statuses_count": 124,
  "lang": "en",
  "contributors_enabled": false,
  "is_translator": false,
  "is_translation_enabled": false,
  "profile_background_color": "131516",
  "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif",
  "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif",
  "profile_background_tile": true,
  "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg",
  "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg",
  "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1690262984\/1429709252",
  "profile_link_color": "009999",
  "profile_sidebar_border_color": "EEEEEE",
  "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "EFEFEF",
  "profile_text_color": "333333",
  "profile_use_background_image": true,
  "has_extended_profile": false,
  "default_profile": false,
  "default_profile_image": false,
  "following": true,
  "follow_request_sent": false,
  "notifications": false
 },{
 "id": 694476444991229955,
 "id_str": "694476444991229955",
 "text": "Got it",
 "sender": {
  "id": 1690262984,
  "id_str": "1690262984",
  "name": "Ashok Kumar T",
  "screen_name": "Ashok_kumar_T",
  "location": "Trivandrum",
  "description": "",
  "url": null
  },
  "protected": false,
  "followers_count": 68,
  "friends_count": 32,
  "listed_count": 0,
  "created_at": "Thu Aug 22 06:52:53 +0000 2013",
  "favourites_count": 5,
  "utc_offset": 19800,
  "time_zone": "Chennai",
  "geo_enabled": true,
  "verified": false,
  "statuses_count": 124,
  "lang": "en",
  "contributors_enabled": false,
  "is_translator": false,
  "is_translation_enabled": false,
  "profile_background_color": "131516",
  "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif",
  "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif",
  "profile_background_tile": true,
  "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg",
  "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg",
  "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1690262984\/1429709252",
  "profile_link_color": "009999",
  "profile_sidebar_border_color": "EEEEEE",
  "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "EFEFEF",
  "profile_text_color": "333333",
  "profile_use_background_image": true,
  "has_extended_profile": false,
  "default_profile": false,
  "default_profile_image": false,
  "following": true,
  "follow_request_sent": false,
  "notifications": false
 }]`

 keys := make([]PublicKey,0)
 err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &keys)
 if err == nil {
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", keys)
 } else {
  fmt.Println(err)
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", keys)
 }
 myId := keys[l].Id
 fmt.Printf(myId)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to print the identifier of the second array element, then use this code:

```
myId := keys[1].ID  // l changed 1, Id changed to ID
fmt.Println(myId)
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/TV7VDrcpEb)